# Oracle - PL/SQL Developer shows column name in a PIVOT query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

In PLSQL Developer, a pivot query is OK when column name is 9 characters long but garbled when 10 characters long.
[image]

Character set for the database and environment variable is `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`. PLSQL Developer version is `14.0.5.1986(64bit)` and Oracle version is `11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production`. Is it because of exceeding column name length limit for oracle ? Why there's no exception or error popped up ?

Comment: It is not an error. You may provide column names using `as colname` in the `pivot_in_clause`. If you don't provide column names Oracle will generate them for you

Comment: Seems oracle fails to check column name length for chinese characters. It will throw `ORA-01401 value too large for column` if column name is in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the columns an alias:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 'your string' AS name FROM DUAL)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(1)
  FOR name IN (
    'your string' AS alias1,
    'other string' AS alias2
  )
)
```

or, if you want to use a non-ASCII alias then use quoted identifiers:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 'your string' AS name FROM DUAL)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(1)
  FOR name IN (
    'your string' AS "non-ASCII alias1",
    'other string' AS "non-ASCII alias2"
  )
)
```

Comment: Giving an alias is forcing a detection on column name length, and throws error when column name too long. Good.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 30 bytes until the version 12.2 when it was changed to 128. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9522337900346184952
Additionaly, chinese characters are multibyte characters. Try to give shorter alias names to the pivoted columns to avoid the problem.
You can detect multibyte characters using something like this:

```sql
WHERE Length(column) < LengthB(column)
```

Regards,